# Nonhomogeneous Cauchy-Euler DE

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Find the general solution to the differential equation

$$t^2y'' + ty' - y = ln(t)$$

So far, I have $$y = c_1t^{-1} + c_2t$$

but I'm having trouble finding the particular solution. I'm trying to use variation of parameters to obtain the solution, but I get nasty looking equations that I can't seem to integrate. This is how I have it set up:

\begin{align*}tu_1' + t^{-1}u_2' &= 0\\ u_1' - t^{-2} u_2' &= \ln(t)/t^2 \end{align*}

Any help? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Hint:**

Try with the Cramer's Rule:
\begin{align*}
u_1'&=\frac{\begin{vmatrix}0&t^{-1}\\\ln(t)/t^2&-t^{-2}\end{vmatrix}}{\begin{vmatrix}t&t^{-1}\\1&-t^{-2}\end{vmatrix}}&\text{ and }\quad u_2'&=\frac{\begin{vmatrix}t&0\\1&\ln(t)/t^2\end{vmatrix}}{\begin{vmatrix}t&t^{-1}\\1&-t^{-2}\end{vmatrix}}
\end{align*}

Comment: Found it! I kept on computing $(t^{-2})(t)$ as $t^{-3}$ instead of $t^{-1}$... Doh.

Answer (score 1):

Let $t = \mathrm{e}^s$ we then have
$$
\frac{d}{dt} = \frac{ds}{dt}\frac{d}{ds} = \mathrm{e}^{-s}\frac{d}{ds}\\
\frac{d^2}{dt^2} = \mathrm{e}^{-s}\frac{d}{ds}\mathrm{e}^{-s}\frac{d}{ds} = -\mathrm{e}^{-2s}\frac{d}{ds} + \mathrm{e}^{-2s}\frac{d^2}{ds^2}
$$
so your ode becomes
$$
\mathrm{e}^{2s}\left[-\mathrm{e}^{-2s}\frac{d}{ds} + \mathrm{e}^{-2s}\frac{d^2}{ds^2}\right]y + \mathrm{e}^s\mathrm{e}^{-s}\frac{dy}{ds} - y = s
$$
or
$$
\frac{d^2y}{ds^2} - \frac{dy}{ds} + \frac{dy}{ds} - y = \frac{d^2y}{ds^2} -y = s
$$
which you can solve for the general solution then change back to $t$ then you have your particular integral.